# Example of an $R$-module $M$ that is not simple but $\mathrm{End}_R(M)$ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I came across Schur's theorem:

> If an $R$-module $M$ is simple, then $\mathrm{End}_R(M)$ is a skew field. ($M$ is simple if the only submodule are $M$ and $0$, and $M \neq 0$.)

I heard that it doesn't have an reciproc. Can you guys give me an example of an $R$-module $M$ that is not simple but $\mathrm{End}_R(M)$ is a field, and explain way? I've struggle a bit.

Comment: For $M$ to be simple you also want $M \neq 0$.

Comment: Thats right, thanks!

Comment: And we should probably clear up that by "field" you must be allowing noncommutativity, as in a division ring/skew field. The statement you're citing is not true otherwise. So in your question, are you truly looking for a module with an endomorphism ring which is a (commutative) field? Or will a skew field be fine?

Comment: @rschwieb: I changed _field_ to _skew field_.

Comment: Thanks for the support! I didn't know the existence of skew fields. In my contrey we use the naming: comutative and non-comutative fields.

Comment: @HurjuiIonut yes, I thought that might be the case. Just letting you know how it is in English for the most part

Comment: @rschwieb, Glad i've learned something new, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K$ be some field and consider the two matrices
$$
 A =
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\quad\text{and}\quad
B =
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and let $R = K\langle X,Y \rangle$ be the $K$-subalgebra of $\mathrm{M}_2(K)$ generated by these two matrices. Consider $M = K^2$ as an $R$-module via the usual matrix multiplication.

Because $R$ is a unital $K$-algebra every $R$-endomorphism of $M$ must be $K$-linear. Each $K$-linear endomorphism $f$ of $M = K^2$ is given by multiplication with a $2 \times 2$-matrix $F$, and that $f$ is already an $R$-module homomorphism is equivalent to $f$ commuting with the action of both $A$ and $B$ on $K^2$, i.e. $F$ commuting with $A$ and $B$.

Now an easy calculation shows that every matrix which commutes with both $A$ and $B$ is already a scalar multiple of the identity matrix. Thus $\mathrm{End}_R(M) = K$ consists of multiplication with scalars. But $M$ is not simple, because $\langle e_1 \rangle$ is a one-dimensional submodule.

---

In the case of modules over a $K$-algebra we case see why the converse of Schur does not necessarily hold: If $V$ is a module over a $K$-algebra $A$, then every $a \in A$ gives an endomorphism $f_a \colon V \to V$, $v \mapsto a.v$. For a linear map $g \colon V \to V$ to be an $A$-module homomorphism we need $g$ to respect certain subspaces of $V$. If for example $v \in V$ is an eigenvector of $f_a$ to some eigenvector $\lambda$ then the same goes for $g(a)$. So $g$ must respect the eigenspaces of the endomorphisms $f_a$.

Observations like this can be used to easily construct modules with one-dimensional $A$-endomorphism rings, i.e. every $A$-endomorphism is given by multiplication with a scalar from $K$. But as we have seen above this does not suffice to show that the module is simple.

(If a remember correcty Verma modules of semisimple, complex (finite dimensional?) Lie algebras are a nice example of this, because the heighest weight vectors must be invariant under module homomorphisms, but they already generate the whole module.)

---

A interesting observation is that if $M$ is an $R$-module such that $\mathrm{End}_R(M)$ is a skew field, then $M$ is indecomposable: If we have $M = M_1 \oplus M_2$ for some submodules $M_1$ and $M_2$ then we have a projection $p \colon M \to M$, i.e. a module homomorphism with $p^2 = p$, such that $\ker p = M_1$ and $\mathrm{im} \ p = M_2$. But because $\mathrm{End}_R(M)$ is a skew field it follows from $p^2 = p$ that $p = 0$ or $p = 1$, so either $M_1 = M$ or $M_2 = M$.

Comment: For the first part i have the problem that i don't  know what an algebra is. Can you give me something to read on this topic? About the last part, how is that suppose to help with the problem? Btw, good observation.

Comment: Roughly speaking a $K$-algebra an $K$-vector space $A$ together with a multiplication $\cdot$ such that $(A,+,\cdot)$ is also a ring and the multiplication $\cdot$ is $K$-bilinear. Think of polynomial rings over $K$ or endomorphism rings of $K$-vector spacs. (I think you find a more detailed explanation in most algebra books; see for example 1.2. [here](https://www.ime.usp.br/~repslie/junior/lectures/lecture1.pdf). For this counter examples it is enough to think of $R$ as a ring.

Comment: The last part is just a useful remark. The non-equivalence of simple and indecomposable may motivitate why the converse of Schur does not hold.

Comment: And so, $R$ is a subring of $M_2(K)$ such as $R=\langle{A,B}\rangle$? If that so, how i define the multiplication? And way the $f$ aplication have to commute with $A$ and $B$?

Comment: $R$ is, as a $K$-vector space, spanned by the products $X_1 \dotsm X_n$ with $X_i \in \{A,B\}$, i.e. by all possible (iterated) products of $A$ and $B$ (notice that this includes $I = A^0 = B^0$). The product on $R$ is just the usual matrix product, the module structure on $K^2$ the usual matrix-vector multiplication.

Comment: If $f \colon K^2 \to K^2$ is an $R$-endomorphism then we must have $f(\lambda v) = f((\lambda I) \cdot v) = (\lambda I) \cdot f(v) = \lambda f(v)$ for all $\lambda \in K$, because $\lambda I \in R$. In the same way $f(A \cdot v) = A \cdot f(v)$ and $f(B \cdot v) = B \cdot f(v)$ for all $v \in K^2$ because $A,B \in R$. As $f(w) = F(w)$ for all $w \in K^2$ this just means that $FA = AF$ and $FB = BF$.